# Connection to a tunneled MySQL with PHP PDO on Mac Osx Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, mac, php, mysql, ssh-tunnel

On Mac OS (snow leopard) I have a SSH tunnel so that my local 3306 port is forwarded to remote MySQL. Apps like Navicat can establish connection successfuly.

But PHP's PDO can't connect and gives an error:

```
PDO::__construct(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///tmp/mysql.sock)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819592/error-when-connecting-to-mysql-using-php-pdo

You have to use tcp/ip, not sockets. Try 127.0.0.1 instead of 'localhost'.